# Java Session invalidate and timeout does not work

Tags: java, security, session, servlets, timeout

All works fine but the logout and the session destroy doesnt work and i dont know why.

Why i can get access to protected Area if session is invalidate or session-timeout is reach.

Look at this **[HTTP-Server-Monitor](http://www.brackwasser.ch/img/sessioninvalidate.png)**

```
'http://localhost:8080/psg/admin/'

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>My First Sec Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        ..
```

**Login Servlet** mapped to /admin/

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (session != null) {
        session.setAttribute("ID", session.getId());
        session.setAttribute("User", request.getRemoteUser());
        session.setAttribute("isAuthenticated", true);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

**Logout Servlet** mapped to /admin/logout

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if(session!=null){
        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
    }
```

The same issue if the session-timeout must be destroy the session. 
I can also get a valid session after this Duration if i enter the protected area /psg/admin/

```
<session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
```

Comment: Are you using basic authentication? Then your logout will not work, since browser will resend user credentials on every request.

Comment: Yes i use Digist authentication. I think is similar to basic. Thank you Gas for your Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of basic and digest authentication browser will resend user credentials, so effectively there is no logout, only session invalidation.

You need to use form-based authentication for logout to work.

Comment: By _form-based authentication_ do you mean the Spring security? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Lucky no, I mean Java EE form based authentication, not any Spring related. Proper Java EE authentication is defined in the `web.xml` file in the `<login-config><auth-method>FORM</auth-method>...` element.